# Solr 7.4 org.apache.solr.common.SolrException Error opening new searcher

Tags: solr

I have setup Solr 7.4 cluster with 2 nodes.

Sometimes, when one of the nodes resets or crashes, I encounter this error and I do not know why this happens!!!??

I have to add a new replica for this Shard and remove the broken Replica to solve this problem 
[image]

update :

I found this log :

```
 ERROR (qtp1543148593-14719) [   ] o.a.s.s.HttpSolrCall null:org.apache.solr.core.SolrCoreInitializationException: SolrCore 'facebook_prime_archive_shard1_replica_n1' is not available due to init failure: Error opening new searcher
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:1590)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.init(HttpSolrCall.java:249)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:469)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:377)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:323)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:219)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:760)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:678)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:1012)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:867)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1135)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$13(CoreContainer.java:681)
at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:197)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:209)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:2126)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:2246)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initSearcher(SolrCore.java:1095)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:984)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.index.IndexNotFoundException: no segments* file found in LockValidatingDirectoryWrapper(NRTCachingDirectory(MMapDirectory@/home/solr/data/facebook_prime_archive_shard1_replica_n1/data/index.20190106105338751 lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@136d9ea2; maxCacheMB=48.0 maxMergeSizeMB=4.0)): files: [_1rpu.dii, _1rpu.dim, _1rpu.fdt, _1rpu.fdx, _1rpu.fnm, _1rpu.nvd, _1rpu.nvm, _1rpu.si, _1rpu_7xm.liv, _1rpu_Lucene50_0.doc, _1rpu_Lucene50_0.pos, _1rpu_Lucene50_0.tim, _1rpu_Lucene50_0.tip, _1rpu_Lucene70_0.dvd, _1rpu_Lucene70_0.dvm, _2mq1.dii, _2mq1.dim, _2mq1.fdt, _2mq1.fdx, _2mq1.fnm, _2mq1.nvd, _2mq1.nvm, _2mq1.si, _2mq1_8i5.liv, _2mq1_Lucene50_0.doc, _2mq1_Lucene50_0.pos, _2mq1_Lucene50_0.tim, _2mq1_Lucene50_0.tip, _2mq1_Lucene70_0.dvd, _2mq1_Lucene70_0.dvm, _3ljq.dii, _3ljq.dim, _3ljq.fdt, _3ljq.fdx, _3ljq.fnm, _3ljq.nvd, _3ljq.nvm, _3ljq.si, _3ljq_8iz.liv, _3ljq_Lucene50_0.doc, _3ljq_Lucene50_0.pos, _3ljq_Lucene50_0.tim, _3ljq_Lucene50_0.tip, _3ljq_Lucene70_0.dvd, _3ljq_Lucene70_0.dvm, _496c.dii, _496c.dim, _496c.fdt, _496c.fdx, _496c.fnm, _496c.nvd, _496c.nvm, _496c.si, _496c_Lucene50_0.doc, _496c_Lucene50_0.pos, _496c_Lucene50_0.tim, _496c_Lucene50_0.tip, _496c_Lucene70_0.dvd, _496c_Lucene70_0.dvm, _496c_d9u.liv, _4xpr.dii, _4xpr.dim, _4xpr.fdt, _4xpr.fdx, _4xpr.fnm, _4xpr.nvd, _4xpr.nvm, _4xpr.si, _4xpr_Lucene50_0.doc, _4xpr_Lucene50_0.pos, _4xpr_Lucene50_0.tim, _4xpr_Lucene50_0.tip, _4xpr_Lucene70_0.dvd, _4xpr_Lucene70_0.dvm, _4xpr_geo.liv, _6cxz.dii, _6cxz.dim, _6cxz.fdt, _6cxz.fdx, _6cxz.fnm, _6cxz.nvd, _6cxz.nvm, _6cxz.si, _6cxz_Lucene50_0.doc, _6cxz_Lucene50_0.pos, _6cxz_Lucene50_0.tim, _6cxz_Lucene50_0.tip, _6cxz_Lucene70_0.dvd, _6cxz_Lucene70_0.dvm, _6cxz_f2a.liv, _7psg.dim, _7psg.fdt, _7psg.fdx, _7psg.nvd, _7psg.si, _7psg_Lucene50_0.doc, _7psg_Lucene50_0.pos, _7psg_Lucene50_0.tim, _7psg_Lucene50_0.tip, _7psg_Lucene70_0.dvd, _7psg_Lucene70_0.dvm, write.lock]
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:832)
at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.<init>(SolrIndexWriter.java:124)
at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.create(SolrIndexWriter.java:97)
at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.createMainIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:257)
at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.getIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:131)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:2087)
... 12 more
```

Comment: need more details. what's the problem?

Comment: @Mysterion  tanks. My problem  is how to restore and fix this two replica ?and why this happens? I didn’t find good thing in log

Comment: The log for that particular node should include a proper stack trace with the actual error message.

Comment: @Mysterion  I added the log to question .. please check again.

Comment: @MatsLindh I added the log to question .. please check again.

Comment: The error message tells you that your index files has disappeared. Are you running multiple solr nodes from the same data directory? Are you using a shared file system (NFS/smb)? Is the disk full? What can be the reason for the `segments`-files disappearing suddenly?

Comment: @MatsLindh I have two separate servers and running one Solr on per server. When a heavy queue was executed, one of the servers crashed and after the restart, ‍`facebook_prime_archive_shard1_replica_n1` and  `news_production_archive_shard3_replica_n4` were damaged

Comment: That sounds like you had a file system failure, which left the index in a broken state. Check the syslog to see if the process was OOM-ed (which means that the process was killed off by the underlying operating system), or if the server crashed physically, having a raid controller with battery backup can be helpful.